# Как в джаве с помощью formatter выровнять данные в колонках

Tags: java

Возникла проблема, я считал csv файл, но для вывода нужно чтобы были ровные колонки. А у меня выводится не ровно, именно колонки

```java
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(",");

    String val = String.format(
        "%1$6s     %2$s     %3$6s     %4$6s     %5$6s", 
        values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]
    );
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: а что, `\t` (символ табуляции) не подходит?

Comment: В данном форматтере ширина всех колонок кроме второй (для `values[1]`) явно задана в 6 символов.  Так что если длина этого элемента массива варьируется или ширины других элементов имеют переменную длину больше 6, колонки не будут ровными.  Кроме того, для заданного вывода можно не использовать индексы аргументов.